# Remove element at a given index of a Stack that is a part of linked list of stacks

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am building a StackList. Which is a linked-list of StackNodes. Each stack on StackNode is of constant size (it is an int array). If a stack is full I use malloc to create a new StackNode and append it to the StackList.

I need to implement a function call

```
int popAt(int index);
```

which should return the element specified by the index.

**Scenario:**
Each stack has length = 10;
StackList has total of 5 stacks. thus number of elements in my StackList is 10 per stack * 5 sets = 41 - 50 ( at max it can be 50). I want to remove the element at index = 25. Which means it is at 2ed StackNode of my StackList and 4th index in that StackNode's stack. When I remove this 25th element, i need to push every element on top of it down by one element.

**My solution:**

```
Copy elements on 2nd stack that is above 24th element one position down.
do {
    Copy next StackNode->stack's first element to the end of Current stacks
    //Problem here
    select next StackNode
} while ( linked list has StackNodes)
```

Problem:
I want to shift all elements in the stack one position down. Is it possible to do this without iterating through the array(a stack on each StackNode) because if I have n number of StackNode then I need to iterate thorough n * stack size. i.e. if my 3ed stack start at 0x8000 then actualy data starts at 0x8004 since I remove the first element and appended it to end of 2nd stack. So I need to put value 0x8004 to 0x8000 and so on until 0x8028 to 0x8024, then continue doing that for all other stacks. Is there a better solution than using a for loop to move every element. I know the function memcpy but since memory addresses overlap I not sure if its a good idea to pass in

```
memcpy(0x8000, 0x8004, 9) //assume my stack size is 10;
```

Note:

Linked list is of type StackNode defined by following struct

```
struct StackNode {
    int* stack;
    StackSet* nextStack;
    StackSet* previousStack;
}
```

Hope I am clear enough :)
Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth you don't use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Please don't tag your question as both `c` and `c++`, because the answers will vary *greatly* in both languages.

Comment: 1. Pick a language - are you using C or C++? 2. If you are using C, then `realloc` may be handy?

Comment: I do know std:stack but the question is about implementing my own List of stacks. I am sure C++ doesnt have it too. I am preparing for a interview and ran in to this question.  Thats why I wrote down the question before my solution and problem I am facing. Thanks for the help though. I changed tags to better reflect the question.

Comment: "I know the function memcpy but since memory addresses overlap I not sure if its a good idea " -- That's like saying that you know cyanide is poisonous but you're not sure whether it's a good idea to eat it. From the memcpy man page: "The memory areas must not overlap. Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap." -- What part don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `memcpy()` doesn't work if the memory areas are overlapping.

For such cases there exists a different function, [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html). It works the same as `memcpy()` but contains additional checks to handle overlapping memory regions.